# How to prevent React from rendering twice setState function?

Tags: reactjs

I called a function that changes the state of a boolean property of an object, but since React is rendering my SetState function twice, the value goes from False to True and then from True to False, so i end up getting the same value i had before calling the function.

```
const updateCheck = () => {
    setTodoList((prev) => {
      const prevAux = [...prev];
      const pos = prevAux.indexOf(item);
      prevAux[pos].checked = !prevAux[pos].checked;
      return prevAux;
    });
```

This is where i call the function from:

```
<div
  onClick={updateCheck}
  className={
    item.text !== ""
      ? `${css.liButton} ${css.check} ${
          item.checked ? css["check-true"] : css["check-false"]
        }`
      : css.none
  }
>
  <FontAwesomeIcon className={css.icon} icon="fa-check"></FontAwesomeIcon>
</div>
```

Does someone know how i can solve it or whether i'm making a mistake?

Comment: Can you show us how you call this code? If it's from, say, a click event, i would **not** expect it to be called twice.

Comment: yes, it's a click event of a div element

Comment: Please show us that code.

Comment: i just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this implementation:

```
setTodoList((prev) => {
  return prev.map((todo) => {
    if (todo === item) {
      return { ...todo, checked: !todo.checked };
    }
    return todo;
  });
});
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: It worked!! Thanks! But why was my way wrong?

Comment: You didn't have the (todo === item) condition I presume. This is limiting the number of renders to 1: When todo === item